# How to make an if statement to check for if a String is greater than 10 characters

Tags: java, string, if-statement

So far I have been able to figure out how many characters are in the string, I can't seem to figure out an if statement to check if the character has more than 10 characters and if it does only display the first 10.

```
import java.text.*

public class StringPracticeCoding

{
 public static void main (String[] args)

   {
      //local constants

  //local variables

  //phrase input by the user
  String sentence = "I am somebody, I am worthy";


  /********************   Start main method  *****************/

  System.out.println("Length of String: " + sentence.length());

      System.out.println(sentence.substring(0,10));
```

yes it has to be an if statement

Comment: How do you check if a number is greater than 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the purpose of the question. You have already done a `sentence.length()` - Anyhow here's the code to test if it's more than 10 characters long:-

```
String sentence = "I am somebody, I am worthy";
if (sentence.length() > 10) {
    // Do stuff
} else {
    // Do different stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, yea I butchered the title a bit, I knew how to display up to 10 I just couldn't figure out the if

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestProject {

    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException {
        String sentence = "I am somebody, I am worthy";
        if(sentence.length() > 10){
            System.out.println("Greater then 10");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Less then 10");
        }
    }
}
```